# How to split string in SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql-server, database, stored-procedures

My record are as below and it was fixed length. There are space between each data.

```
123 870503-23-5370 021 456 830503-23-5371 031 789 870103-11-5372 041 654 870501-23-5373 051 321 880503-12-5374 061 987 870803-23-5375 071 109 870508-06-5376 081 174 810503-03-5377 091 509 870103-01-5378 101 687 870501-12-5379 131
```

By using a SQL Server 2012 stored procedure, I want to split it as below:

```
123 870503-23-5370 021
456 830503-23-5371 031
789 870103-11-5372 041
654 870501-23-5373 051
.......
```

Comment: Google:  "SQL Server split"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a loop iterating through each set until the length of the string is reached. Then stuffed that into a stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SplitMyFunkyText] @Source nvarchar(MAX)
AS
    DECLARE @Results AS TABLE(Part NVARCHAR(22))
    DECLARE @I INT = 1

    WHILE @I < LEN(@Source)
    BEGIN   
        INSERT INTO @Results
            SELECT SUBSTRING(@Source, @I, 22)

        SET @I = @I + 23
    END

    SELECT * FROM @Results
GO
```

Here is a test using your example value:

```
DECLARE @Source AS NVARCHAR(230)

SET @Source = '123 870503-23-5370 021 456 830503-23-5371 031 789 870103-11-5372 041 654 870501-23-5373 051 321 880503-12-5374 061 987 870803-23-5375 071 109 870508-06-5376 081 174 810503-03-5377 091 509 870103-01-5378 101 687 870501-12-5379 131'

EXEC SplitMyFunkyText @Source
```

Here are the test results:

```
123 870503-23-5370 021
456 830503-23-5371 031
789 870103-11-5372 041
654 870501-23-5373 051
321 880503-12-5374 061
987 870803-23-5375 071
109 870508-06-5376 081
174 810503-03-5377 091
509 870103-01-5378 101
687 870501-12-5379 131
```

PER YOUR SECOND QUESTION: "how about if my splitting record are not in fixed position"

You originally indicated "fixed length" and that is much easier. For records NOT in fixed length the following will work as long as it's in groups of 3 with spaces in between:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SplitMyFunkyText] 
    @Source nvarchar(MAX)
AS
    DECLARE @Results AS TABLE(Part NVARCHAR(22))

    DECLARE @I INT = 1
    DECLARE @NextLength INT = -1
    DECLARE @SubPart1 NVARCHAR(20)
    DECLARE @SubPart2 NVARCHAR(20)
    DECLARE @SubPart3 NVARCHAR(20)

    WHILE @I < LEN(@Source)
    BEGIN
        -- GET 1st SubPart -----------------------------------
        SET @NextLength = CHARINDEX(' ',@Source,@I)

        IF @NextLength > 0
            SET @SubPart1 = SUBSTRING( @Source, @I, @NextLength - @I)
        ELSE
            SET @SubPart1 = SUBSTRING( @Source, @I, LEN(@Source))

        SET @I = @I + LEN(@SubPart1) + 1;

        -- GET 2st SubPart -----------------------------------
        SET @NextLength = CHARINDEX(' ',@Source,@I)

        IF @NextLength > 0
            SET @SubPart2 = SUBSTRING( @Source, @I, @NextLength - @I)
        ELSE
            SET @SubPart2 = SUBSTRING( @Source, @I, LEN(@Source))

        SET @I = @I + LEN(@SubPart2) + 1;

        -- GET 3st SubPart -----------------------------------
        SET @NextLength = CHARINDEX(' ',@Source,@I)

        IF @NextLength > 0
            SET @SubPart3 = SUBSTRING( @Source, @I, @NextLength - @I)
        ELSE
            SET @SubPart3 = SUBSTRING( @Source, @I, LEN(@Source))

        SET @I = @I + LEN(@SubPart3) + 1;

        INSERT INTO @Results
            SELECT @SubPart1 + ' ' + @SubPart2 + ' ' + @SubPart3
    END

    SELECT * FROM @Results
GO
```

Here is a more condensed version that works with non-fixed length fields in groups of 3:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SplitMyFunkyText] 
    @Source nvarchar(MAX)
AS
    DECLARE @Results AS TABLE(Part NVARCHAR(255))

    DECLARE @I INT = 1
    DECLARE @Start INT = 1

    WHILE @I > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @Start = @I
        SET @I = CHARINDEX(' ',@Source, 1+CHARINDEX(' ',@Source, 1+CHARINDEX(' ', @Source, @I + 1)))

        IF @I > 0
            INSERT INTO @Results 
                SELECT SUBSTRING(@Source, @Start, @I - @Start)
        ELSE
            INSERT INTO @Results 
                SELECT SUBSTRING(@Source, @Start, LEN(@Source))
     END

     SELECT * FROM @Results
GO
```

Comment: Hi Don, yes that what I need, and just one more question, how about if my splitting record are not in fixed position example: 123 870503-23-5370 021 456 6606249 031 789 870103-11-5372 041

Comment: I just posted a more condensed version that works with non-fixed length fields in groups of 3 - see the bottom of the answer.